# How can i send get method's data to post method without using view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Suppose, I have a value/data(in my exaple **name**) in the get method.I want to send and access it in the post method without using view.How can I do that?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPerson(ModelMap model,Person person){

    String name="Person Name";
    return "personEdit";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String savePerson(ModelMap model,Person person){
     //I want to access/get **name** here

    return "details";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use modelMap to send the value

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPerson(ModelMap model,Person person){

    String name="Person Name";

        model.addAttribute("name","Person Name");
return "personEdit";
```

}

you can access your value by using JSTL  forexmp : ${name} ..

Comment: It will pass data to view....but i need to send data from get method to post method without using view